God’s Rebuke of Aaron and Miriam - Numbers 12
In Numbers 12 God called Moses, Aaron, and Miriam to the door of the tabernacle. Why did God rebuke Aaron and Miriam for speaking ill of Moses for his Ethiopian wife?

Possibly related: Why did God punish Miriam when it was her & Aaron who spoke against Moses?

@agarza this question focuses on the Cushite wife of Moses and not whether one or both of them should have been punished. It’s a different enough question even if there will inevitably be overlaps.


“And he said, “Hear my words: When there are prophets among you, I the Lord make myself known to them in visions; I speak to them in dreams. Not so with my servant Moses; he is faithful in all my house. With him I speak face to face—clearly, not in riddles, and he beholds the form of the Lord. “Why then were you not afraid to speak against my servant Moses?” And the anger of the Lord was kindled against them, and he departed.”
‭‭Numbers‬ ‭12‬:‭6‬-‭9‬ ‭

Because in questioning Moses about his wife, they were questioning the authenticity of Moses’ revelations, comparing and measuring themselves against Moses. The Cushite wife (likely dark skin) was just a front for a deeper issue they had with Moses and they articulate it ultimately.

“and they said, “Has the Lord spoken only through Moses? Has he not spoken through us also?” And the Lord heard it.”
‭‭Numbers‬ ‭12‬:‭2‬ ‭

Essentially they likely felt they were better and more pure then Moses because Moses introduced a non Hebrew into the mix, or at least on par with Moses, as if to say their revelations received from God should be as weighty as Moses’ and they should have the same ranking and same privileges
The problem was that their revelations were no where near on par with Moses’ God spoke face to face with Moses but He spoke in riddles and cryptically in visions and dreams to them. Thus God’s sovereign decision was called into question, which means though they had issue with their brother Moses in private, they were actually being accusatory toward God. And very disrespectful
It is for this reason that God insisted that Miriam (probably the instigator seeing Aaron was not punished) be put out of the camp for a period of seven days, stating that she should be ashamed of herself and her behavior, daring to question the authority of God. Even if as siblings they might quarrel they cannot bring shame on the father and his decisions indirectly, that was not acceptable toward a father much less God Himself.

“But the Lord said to Moses, “If her father had but spit in her face, would she not bear her shame for seven days? Let her be shut out of the camp for seven days, and after that she may be brought in again.””
‭‭Numbers‬ ‭12‬:‭14‬ ‭

Conslusion
Why did God rebuke Miriam and Aaron for his wife? Because on a deeper level they were questioning indirectly the decision that God had made to appoint Moses as head over all His house even though he married a non Hebrew and was therefore less than in their own eyes. This was not a decision Moses had made on his own let’s not forget, and we know this because God had to press Moses to accept the mandate to free the people of Israel from Egypt. Moses was very reluctant, his reluctance landed Aaron the position of spokesperson for Moses.
It was certainly justified

+1. Good answer - I think it was a pointed rebuke against racism as well.  Thus, God's rebuke had the effect of strengthening the authority of God's appointed prophets and banishing racism.

@Nihil Moses was a prophet foreshadowing Messiah. Messiah's bride is symbolized with dark skin (Ethiopian) as a symbol of previous sin. She is dressed in a white wedding attire showing that she has been made pure from her previous sins. The rejection and criticism of Moses is showing the rejection of Jesus based on the faults of His church. God departing from those who reject His Son because of the complaints against His bride is being warned of here ultimately.

@Biff Ethiopian representing the whole bride of Christ? Can you show me where you get this from please including dark skin and past sin part. Thank you

@NihilSineDeo  SoSolomon 1:5-6 The woman with black skin looking for her love. When she finds him, she clings to him, not letting him go. This is obvious reference to what will be. Moses had a dark skinned wife for a specific purpose that was ordered by God. Yes, Moses' wife represents the fulfillment of Christ's bride that was black from sin, and made pure and worthy of being His bride. Jer13:23 - Can the Ethiopian change his skin, or the leopard his spots? then may ye also do good, that are accustomed to do evil. It's not literal, but symbolic imagery God uses to program ideas into people

@NihilSineDeo Job 30:30 - My skin turns black and falls from me, and my bones burn with heat. The black skin is sin, burning with heat is eternal judgement. Lam4:7 - Her princes were purer than snow, whiter than milk; their bodies were more ruddy than coral, the beauty of their form was like sapphire. Now their face is blacker than soot; they are not recognized in the streets; their skin has shriveled on their bones; it has become as dry as wood. Is not not symbolism showing God's people once righteous, are now unrighteous and receiving judgement?
